# Matlab: Importing functions in a class

Tags: matlab, oop, package

I have a class file in Matlab.

I created i directory structure using the package specifications.

```
+MyPkg
|--+F1
|--+F2
|--+F3
|  |--fun.m
|--myc.m
```

My class is `myc` and it is inserted in the package `MyPkg`.

A function `fun` is saved in subpackage `F3` in the main one.

I want to use function `fun` in my class. How???

Answer (score 2):

You need to refer to `fun` as `MyPkg.F3.fun` everywhere. Unfortunately, full packages must be used explicitly everywhere in MATLAB (or, you must use `import` statements).

Answer (score -1):

The way you are describing using classes is the "old" way of doing it in Matlab.  I don't know how it all works when you use the "old" way, but Class files make life way easier.  I highly recommend them.  This way you can put all of the functions for a class in one file.  For example, you could create a file:

myclass.m

```
classdef myclass
  methods
    function out=add(a,b)
      out=a+b
    end
    function out=subtract(a,b)
      out=a-b
    end
  end
end
```

If you put myclass.m in the same folder as your m-file.  Then you can access the class this way:

```
a=5;
b=3;
asdf=myclass;
c=asdf.add(a,b)
d=asdf.subtract(a,b)
```

There is a more extensive example at the following link:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/brhzttf.html

I hope that helps.

Comment: The OP is talking about _package_ directories, not old-style '@' directories.

Comment: Sorry ... my fault.  I didn't read the question carefully enough.