# How do I perform an import for the entire class in matlab?

Tags: matlab, oop, package

I have a class that uses other classes from another package in multiple functions.  In order to do this, I current have to import the package in each function:

```
classdef foo
    properties
        bar
    end
    methods
        function self = foo()
            foo.bar = 1;
        end

        function fun1(foo)
            import pkg.FooClass;
            val = pkg.FooClass(foo.bar);
        end
        function fun2(foo)
            import pkg.FooClass;
            val = FooClass.fun(foo.bar);
        end
    end
end
```

Is there a way to import packages for the entire class?  I'm looking for something similar to other languages:

```
classdef foo
    import pkg.FooClass;
    properties
        bar
    end
    methods
        function self = foo()
            foo.bar = 1;
        end

        function fun1(foo)
            val = pkg.FooClass(foo.bar);
        end
        function fun2(foo)
            val = FooClass.fun(foo.bar);
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: btw once you import, you dont need to specify the package name `pkg.FooClass`, just refer to the class as `FooClass`

Comment: @Amro sorry and I did know that. This was was just a quick example I put together on the fly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, the [doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/import.html) page says that:

> The import function only affects the import list of the function
>   within which it is used.

So you will either [have to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10528608/97160) specify the full qualified name everywhere, or do an import in each function.

Comment: regrettably packages in MATLAB are not as flexible as in other languages that support namespaces

Comment: No package aliases either :(