# How to reference a class constructor within a package?

Tags: matlab, oop, constructor, package

Suppose that the class `fee` below is defined within a package, e.g., `+fee/fee.m`. In order for the `flip` method to call the class constructor, it seems necessary to use the full namespace, i.e., `foo.fee`. It would be nice if it was possible to define the object without reference to the containing package.

Is there a way to avoid the call `foo.fee`?

```
classdef fee
   properties
      x
      y = 1
   end
   methods
      function self = fee(x)
         self.x = x;
      end
      function self2 = flip(self)
         self2 = foo.fee(self.x);
         self2.y = xor(self.y,1);
      end
   end
end
```

Comment: not really: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10528608/97160, http://stackoverflow.com/q/17050167/97160

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using [import](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/import.html) function? I think it should be possible to do something like this:

```
classdef fee
   properties
      x
      y = 1
   end
   methods
      function self = fee(x)
         self.x = x;
      end
      function self2 = flip(self)
         import(mfilename('class'));           
         self2 = fee(self.x);
         self2.y = xor(self.y,1);
      end
   end
end
```

Comment: That's an improvement, since it means not having to keep track of the enclosing package's name. Still unfortunate, since one would hope that a method would have direct access to its own class's constructor.